# How to list autocmd groups in Vim?

Tags: vim, autocmd

In my `.vimrc` I want to define several [autocmd groups](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-groups). Also, I want to avoid conflicts with any pre-existing groups. How can I list currently defined groups in Vim?

Comment: https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-list

Comment: I guess it's safe to say using a `vimrc_` prefix is almost sure not to generate any conflicts.

Comment: @phd That command actually lists auto-commands, not the autocmd groups... Running `autocmd` by itself lists them, but that doesn't appear to be documented. Added an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This actually doesn't appear to be [documented](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-groups) in Vim's help (only mentions the commands to select or delete a group), but at least on my Vim 8.2.0318, the command `:augroup` by itself lists all the defined autocmd groups.

I get this on pretty much stock Vim setup:

```
:augroup
filetypedetect  syntaxset  filetypeplugin  filetypeindent  vimStartup  gzip  matchparen  FileExplorer  Network  tar  Vimball
```

The `:autocmd` command, which lists all auto-commands will end up listing groups *as well*, but it's of course more convenient to get them directly from `:augroup`.

If you want to get that into a Vim variable, use the `execute()` function for it:

```
let groups = split(execute('augroup'))
```